# How to use typescript when I don't know if my data conforms to a Interface, but for a React component I need it to have X data depending on option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, schema

I have a React component `<PanelSettings>`

This component receives props like `showBorderConfiguration`, `showXAxisConfiguration` and a `componentId`

This `componentId` is what I use to grab the data of the component from the store.

Now, my component data could be implement different interfaces coming from a base `ComponentData` one, but more specialized.

Example: `ComponentDataWithBorder` or `ComponentDataWithXAxis` (just an example name).

The problem is:

If I have my `<SettingsPanel showXAxisConfiguration={true} componentId='aaabbb'>` but when I grab the data from the store for component `aaabbb` it is of type `ComponentDataWithBorder` and not of type `ComponentDataWithXAxis` (i.e it doesn't have the property xAxis but I'm telling the SettingsPanel to show X Axis configuration and it will crash the app when trying to load it).

What would be a way to solve this issue? How can I use typescript to ensure that `<SettingsPanel showXAxisConfiguration={true} componentId='aaabbb'>` will have data of type `ComponentDataWithXAxis` when I require the `showXAxisConfiguration`, or what is the way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

In typescript, you can use [Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types.

For example:

```
const data: ComponentDataWithBorder | ComponentDataWithXAxis = await getData();
const hasXAxis: boolean = data.x_axis !== undefined;
```

Later you can make your conditions more specific, for rendering:

```
{props.showXAxisConfiguration && hasXAxis && (<>Render Something</>)}
```

Comment: You'd need to adjust this to cater for your actual object, since `x_axis` is probably not the prop your looking for.